# Configure Dot .Net Application in windows server

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting

I uploaded a dot .net project into my host gator windows hosting space.It is showing error. But I don't know how resolve it.. Please assist me to overcome that.

[image]

This is the error I am facing... My website URL is [image: buseticket]

Thanks in advance...

My web.config Section is...

```
    <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
         <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
<remove name="jsonSerialization">
<section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
<section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>         
</sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a duplicate section defined !
Add this `<remove name="jsonSerialization">` in your web.config file and try ,

```
<remove name="jsonSerialization" />
<section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition=**strong text**
```

Comment: My bad ! try with slash  `<remove name="jsonSerialization" />`